# Get walking instructions from google maps and store that instructions as string

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, speech-recognition

I have tried to run google maps in front and in background I am running my speech recognition but I learned that I can not run voice recogniser in background. Is there someway to get the speech directions given by google maps into string. I want keywords like "left", "right" etc.

Comment: check this open source project https://github.com/GeeksEmpireNet/PinPicsOnMap

Comment: I want keywords like (left or right) if there is a road turning left or right respectively on google maps while a person is walking.

Answer (score -1):

Google Maps Directions API has [html_instructions](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Steps) which may be contained by the 'Step' on the Directions API result. This html_instructions contains formatted instructions for this step, presented as an HTML text string. You can see that it contains keyword that you are looking for like "left" and "right". You can then integrate this API to your android app.